# Bootstrap 3 tabs not loading in the correct place

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to setup some bootstrap tabs and instead of loading the content from different tabs in the same place, the first tabs content is at the top, then the next tab displays below the first, and the third below the second. Why are they not all showing at the top of the display area?

```
          <div class="row">
        <div class="listingInteractions">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs listingTabs" id="requestTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#openQuoteTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">OPEN QUOTE REQUESTS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#closedQuoteTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">CLOSED QUOTE REQUESTS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="#bookedEventsTab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">BOOKED EVENTS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>




            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="openQuoteTab">
                    hello

                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="closedQuoteTab">
                    <div>
                        rofl
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bookedEventsTab">
                    <div>
                        haha
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You are going to need to provide more code than just this if you want people to be able to help you out. Alternatively you can create a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) which is super helpful.

Comment: I've made a fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/02ymq3b5/ and to me it seems to be working

Comment: This is set up correctly for the tabs. However you don't typically put content directly inside a .row without having a column class around the children. If it's a full width situation, just put a .container around it and don't put the row class.